# Android ViewPager update getPageWidth dynamically without reinflalting page

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I use [this library](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) to have a `ViewPager` that scrolls vertically. The `ViewPager` has two children (children are `View`'s, not `Fragment`'s): I want one of them to always be the full screen's size, while the the should always be wrapping the content of the view dynamically (the `View` has some `EditText`'s that may from one line to several, increasing the size of the `View`).

The approach I currently have is using the `getPageWidth()` to set the height (since it's a `VerticalViewPager`, width becomes height) of the view to a fraction of the `ViewPager`, which is measured using `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()`. Once it's measured, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (I also use`return POSITION_NONE;` in `getItemPosition(Object object)`), so that the `ViewPager` reinflates the page, having the correct value for fraction in `getPageWidth()`.

Then, every time the `EditText` get a new line, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which repeats the process above.

This is a very sketchy solution, since the user can observe the `View` being recreated, as well as the soft keyboard goes off and on.

So my question is the following: is there a way to update the width of a page (which is height in my case) dynamically, without recreating the `View`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ViewPager viewPager; //your viewpager object
viewPager.getLayoutParams().width = DESIRED_NEW_WIDTH; //sets the width of view
viewPager.requestLayout(); //updates view so that change to width takes place
```

I believe you may still determine your desired new width by getting the `ViewPager` width with `viewPager.getWidth()` or storing `viewPager.getLayoutParams().width` to a variable. And then determining the desired fraction.